# Is there a logical symbol for independence?

Tags: logic, notation

In propositional logic, the operator $\rightarrow$ denotes implication, so
$$
    A \rightarrow B
$$
means: If A is true, it follows that B is also true.

**Question:** Is there a symbol $???$ to denote the independence of two statments?
$$
A\space ???\space B
$$
meaning that neither does A imply B nor vice versa. I guess, this could be written as
$$
\neg(A \rightarrow B)\space \land\space\neg(B \rightarrow A)
$$
but I am looking for a more concise notation.

Comment: If we do NOT have $A\implies B$, then $A$ must be true and $B$ must be false. But then, we have $B\implies A$.

Comment: Your proposal means that $A \text { ??? } B$ is FALSE when both $A$ and $B$ are FALSE. Maybe relevant [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate): The difference is that $A \text { NAND } B$ is TRUE when both are FALSE.

Comment: @Peter I don't think so, because, "A does not imply B" is not the same as "A does imply *not* B".

Comment: @HermannSchachner But your suggested expression says "not (A implies B)" instead of "A implies (not B)". Calculate the truth table for the suggested expression.

Comment: I suspect that what is more in line with your idea of independence is $$\bigg(\exists x.\lnot (Px \to Qx)\bigg) \land \bigg(\exists y.\lnot (Qy \to Py)\bigg)$$

Comment: Peter is correct, $\lnot (A \to B) \land \lnot (B \to A)$ is equivalent to $A \land \lnot B \land B \land \lnot A$ an obvious contradiction.  It isn't the same as a nand gate.

Comment: There is no concise notation in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If logical independence is meant -- which presumably it is -- then we normally say that $B$ is logically independent of a given $A$ if neither $B$ nor $\neg B$ logically follows from $A$.

So two-way logical independence comes to this: $A \nvdash B$ and $B \nvdash A$ and $A \nvdash \neg B$ and $B \nvdash \neg A$ too. Or equivalently $\nvdash A \to B$ and $\nvdash B \to A$ and $\nvdash A \to \neg B$ and $\nvdash B \to \neg A$.

Or you might want to do all this with a semantic rather than a syntactic turnstile. But either way, 
you need more than bare material conditionals, then, to regiment a claim of logical independence.

Comment: For me, the crossed out semantic tunstile will fulfill its purpose.

Comment: I think it isn't actually the turnstiles that make any kind of difference, it is the hidden suggestion of free variables.

Comment: @DanielV That can't be right -- given we can talk of the logical independence of wffs of the propositional calculus where there are no free variables.

Comment: The use of $\vdash$ or $\vDash$ is one good way to do this. Another classical way, which is unfortunately little known now, is to look at strict implication ⥽, a different interpretation of "$A$ implies $B$" than material implication.  The key point of using $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ is that they quantify over interpretations - strict implication  makes the modal nature of this more apparent.

Comment: Piotr Jaśkowski's way of doing propositional logic was to write, for example, weakening as $\Pi A \Pi B.(A \to (B \to A))$ by universally quantifying over propositional variables.  We implicitly do that as well when we talk about independence of propositional formulas.  For example, "proof by cases is stronger than disjunctive syllogism" would be written 
$$\Sigma P.\bigg( (\Pi ABX.(A \to X) \to (B \to X) \to (A \lor B) \to X) \to P)\bigg) \land \bigg((\Pi AB.(A \lor B) \to \lnot A \to B) \not \to P\bigg)$$

Comment: I said it badly when I said "free variables", what I meant was "domain variables" without intention to convey that they were unquantified.  In the same way, the independence of propositional expressions treats propositional variables as quantifiable parts. It isn't the turnstile that does that, unless it is intended that 2 variables on opposite sides of a turnstile sharing the same name are intended to have a separate semantic meaning.

Comment: @CarlMummert Absolutely. I too would ultimately want to say notions like entailment are modal notions, and proof-theoretic/model-theoretic substitutes aren't the real thing. But one battle at a time!